# RedirectMatch 301 rule conflicts with RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to setup 301 redirects for requests from: /category/groceries-and-everyday/household/

Redirecting them to: /category/household/

I have the following rules set up for these requests:

```
# The following is to redirect old urls
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/groceries-and-everyday/household/$ /category/household/

# This is our rewrite rule for SEO friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/$ /category_pages/category.php?category_string=$1&rewrite=1 [NC,QSA]
```

Now when I load /category/groceries-and-everyday/household

I get bounced to: /category/household/?category_string=groceries-and-everyday/household&rewrite=1

I want this to bounce only to: /category/household/

Can somebody please explain why this behaviour is occurring and what changes I should make to achieve my desired result.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight adaption on Starkeen's answer.

Changing the second htaccess rule to have the following rewrite condition appears to work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/groceries-and-everyday/household/(.*)
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/$ /category_pages/category.php?category_string=$1&rewrite=1 [NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try placing the 2nd rule before the 1st rule? Basically switch them.

Comment: This makes absolutely no difference I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the uri **category/household** from your rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/household    RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/$ /category_pages/category.php?category_string=$1&rewrite=1 [NC,QSA]
```

otherwise your rewrite pattern  **^category/(.*)/$** will also rewrite it to **/category_pages/category.php?category_string=$1&rewrite=1**

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work. The problem is that the rewrite rule needs applied to category/household. The 301 redirect shouldn't be appending the URL parameters to the URL though.